# How should we translate "everything but the kitchen sink" or "the whole enchilada"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, modismos, traducción

There is an idiom that is popular (and old) in English that states "[everything but the kitchen sink](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/kitchen%20sink)."  This is a phrase that means "everything that could be conceived."

Some examples:

- "I realized that there is a request to add everything but the kitchen sink to
  Mozilla." ([link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=122411))
- "We’re watching four storms right now bringing another day of “everything but the kitchen sink” weather!" ([link](https://web.archive.org/web/20121225063503/http://foxnewsinsider.com/2011/01/18/more-everything-but-the-kitchen-sink-weather/))
- "Goldtone cuff bracelet adorned with everything but the kitchen sink." ([link](https://web.archive.org/web/20111121210102/http://www.avarosescloset.bigcartel.com/product/everything-but-the-kitchen-sink-bracelet))

This is similar to "[the whole enchilada](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/whole%20enchilada)."  That phrase, by comparison, means "absolutely everything."

- "I’ve got the whole enchilada going on: an ethnic necklace, a long beaded necklace, long feather earrings, thin woven bracelets and a wooden ring." ([link](http://thehouseintheclouds.com/2011/07/20/the-whole-enchilada/))
- "Today, our challenge is to make a few 3x3 cards, matching envelopes and a cute box to store them in....in other words, the whole enchilada!" ([link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210118180358/https://www.splitcoaststampers.com/forums/technique-lovers-challenge-f44/tlc171-whole-enchilada-t352435.html))

What would a good translation of these phrases be?  Are there idioms in Spanish that compare to these?

Comment: In Mexico when you order food "with the lot" or "with everything" it seems to always be called a "cubano".

Comment: Another one in English could be "the whole kit and caboodle".

Comment: I think for this to become a great question you should really include some few examples with contexts.

Comment: @hippietrail I know far too many people who think that the phrase is "the kitten caboodle".  ;)

Comment: I had to check the spelling, I was going to go with "kaboodle" but it turns out to have a long and interesting history that I forced myself not to read (-:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Spanish idiom used when somebody takes many things with you in your luggage, probably more than what he really needs:

> irse con la casa a cuestas

So a sentence like "He took everything but the kitchen sink" could be translated as "se fue con la casa a cuestas".

In the case of "The whole enchilada" I can't remember any similar idiom in Spanish with the same idiom. The natural way of saying that would be saying "con todo" as Randolf Rincón-Fadul has said. In Spain we can say

> quedarse con todo el pastel

but this expression means to get all the possible benefits from a situation, and it is usually used in a negative way to complain about a controversial operation.

Answer (score 1):

Context translation of your phrases:

> Absolutamente todo.

If you mean about some food it's common to just say:

> Con todo

For example if you want your hamburger with all the ingredients you say:

> Una hamburguesa con todo